# Truncating table before insert in postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, function, stored-procedures, truncate

I'm trying to create a mechanism that will truncate tables every time an insert command is called on them.

First I tried creating a function that gets an array of rows and truncates the table before inserting them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_customers(customers customer[])
    RETURNS VOID AS 
$$  
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE Customers;
    INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CustomerName) SELECT * FROM UNNEST(customers::Customer[]);
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Where Customer is a user-defined type representing a row in the Customers table:

```
CREATE TYPE Customer AS (
  customerid VARCHAR(100),
  customername VARCHAR(100));
```

That worked when I called the function from psql:

```
SELECT * FROM insert_customers(ARRAY[ROW('ID1', 'Name1'),ROW('ID2', 'Name2')]::Customer[]);
```

But I haven't found a way to perform this insert from my java code:

```
String[][] customers = new String[2][];
customers[0] = new String[] { "ID1", "Name1" };
customers[1] = new String[] { "ID2", "Name2" };    

Array sqlArray = connection.createArrayOf("customer", customers);    

CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{ call insert_customers(?) }");
cstmt.setArray(1, sqlArray);
cstmt.execute();
```

Which created the following statement:

```
select * from insert_customers ('{{"ID1", "Name1"},{"ID2", "Name2"}}') as result
```

And threw the following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: malformed record literal: "ID1"\n Detail: Missing left parenthesis.
```

Then I tried creating a trigger that will truncate the table on insert event:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert_customers
    BEFORE INSERT ON Customers
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE truncate_customers();
```

Where **truncate_customers** is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncate_customers()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$  
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE Customers;   
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And that threw the exception:

```
cannot TRUNCATE "customers" because it is being used by active queries in this session
```

Any Ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Modify the function

The query unnest pairs of elements of a text array:

```
select cols[1], cols[2]
from (
    select (ordinality- 1)/2, array_agg(unnest) cols
    from unnest('{"id1", "name1", "id2", "name2"}'::text[]) with ordinality
    group by 1
    ) s

 cols | cols  
------+-------
 id1  | name1
 id2  | name2
(2 rows)
```

Use it in your function so it can have a text array as a parameter:

```
create or replace function insert_customers(text[])
returns void language plpgsql as $$  
begin
    truncate table customers;
    insert into customers (customerid, customername)
    select cols[1], cols[2]
    from (
        select (ordinality- 1)/2, array_agg(unnest) cols
        from unnest($1) with ordinality
        group by 1
        ) s;
end $$;

select insert_customers('{"id1", "name1", "id2", "name2"}');
```

### Modify the trigger function

You cannot truncate the table in a trigger, but you can delete all rows:

```
...
    delete from Customers;
    return new;
...
```

Comment: Awesome answer @klin! One thing that I'm still trying to figure out though is how can I make the function generic for every column number. Specifically this part:  "select cols[1], cols[2] from". When change it to "select cols from" it throws an error because the select returns the array as one field. How can I break the array into separate value?

Comment: The function is projected to insert two columns and you cannot change it not changing the whole logic. However, you can pass to it an array with any even number of elements.

Comment: To generalize the algorithm you need a dynamic sql (create a query text according to number of columns and run it with `execute`).

Comment: Thanks alot @klin!